# Symfony 2.1.x to 2.3.x стоит?

Tags: twig, doctrine, symfony2

Ченджлог довольно большой. Миграция не простая([1](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.2.md),[2](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md)). Есть что нибудь действительно стоящее? Интересует в основном повышение производительности(Doctrine, Twig).
Кто обновлял, как ощущения =)

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, стоит. Один раз обновишься, потом без проблем будешь обновляться до более новых версий.

Самое главное, что там появилось - Composer. Теперь все зависимости через него и жить стало намного проще. Все новые бандлы поддерживают уже только 2.3 и выше. В принципе, обратная совместимость даже в 2.7 на уровне, что любая приложуха и бандлы, написанные для 2.3 будут работать.